# Fastest method to join a lot of tables

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-joins, performance

i have a lot of feature class (see figure 1)
the objective is to create one feature class that combines the attribute table (especially one field) of each feature class

the attribute table of each feature class looks the same (see figure 2).

how can a create the following result? (see figure 3)
the field  'centra_buitengewoon' (each time the last field of the attribute table) would be add to the general attribute table

I was thinking about the tool 'join field' but that one is really, really to slow (7 houres for one feature class and i have around 50 feature class.....

[image: feature class]

[image: attribute table]

[image: result]

Comment: I think you need some sort of automation (like programming/scripting) whereas you do not need to join them manually..??

Comment: looks interesting, how does that works? :)

Comment: My first thought was a union or merge but there's probably a good reason they don't work?

Comment: Have you indexed the column in the "to" table of the join?

Comment: yes a indexed it, but it still takes 7 hour for one table and i have around 50 tables

Comment: That's a long time to join a table. How many records are in the table?

Comment: they are 4185656 records in the table ...